# Can't run os.popen in python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to run this command in python.

```
BB = os.environ["BB"]
BBDISP = os.environ["BBDISP"]
NOW = datetime.datetime.now()
COLOR="green"
MSG="Widgets loaded successfully."
NODE="server01"

retvalue = os.popen("BB BBDISP \"status NODE.thisIsATest COLOR str(NOW) MSG \"").readlines()
print retvalue
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
sh: 1: BB: not found
```

But I"m able to print that variable to screen.

```
print BB
```

The output is

```
/usr/lib/xymon/server/bin/xymon
```

Comment: `"BB"` is a static string which has nothing to do with the variable `BB`.

Comment: Ditto for all the other variable names used in the string.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compose the string from the variables. The preferred way to do this is with the `format` method:

```
cmd = "{BB} {BBDISP} \"status {NODE}.thisIsATest {COLOR} str({NOW}) {MSG} \"".format(
    BB = os.environ["BB"],
    BBDISP = os.environ["BBDISP"],
    NOW = datetime.datetime.now(),
    COLOR="green",
    MSG="Widgets loaded successfully.",
    NODE="server01")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call os.popen the string you pass has to a valid command in the operating system shell. That is if you type the same thing into a terminal window the behaviour will be the same. The question then is:0 is 'BB' a valid command within the operating system shell?

I think  you can achieve what you want to by changing the string to popen to:

```
"%s %s \"status %s.thisIsATest %s %s %s \""%(BB,BBDISP,NODE,COLOR,str(NOW),MSG)
```